# Implementing a "Pythonic" map in Scheme: bad idea?

Tags: scheme, list-comprehension, map-function

In Scheme, the function `(map fn list0 [list1 .. listN])` comes with the restriction that the lists must have the same number of elements. Coming from Python, I'm missing the freedom of Python list comprehensions, which look a lot like `map` above, but without this restriction.

I'm tempted to implement an alternative "my-map", which allows for lists of differing size, iterating through the first N elements of all lists, where N is the length of the shortest list.

For example, let `num` be `10` and `lst` be `(1 2 3)`. With my-map, I hope to write expressions like:

```
(my-map + (circular-list num) lst)))
```

And get:

```
(11 12 13)
```

I have an easier time reading this than the more conventional

```
(map + (lambda (arg) (+ num arg)) lst)
```

or

```
(map + (make-list (length lst) num) lst)
```

Two questions:

- As a Scheme newbie, am I overlooked important reasons for the restriction on `map`?

  Does something like `my-map` already exist in Scheme or in the SRFIs? I did take a look at srfi-42, but either it's not what I'm looking for, or it was, and it wasn't obvious.

Comment: what does list comprehensions have to with map on multiple lists?

Comment: @newacct I wanted map on a single empty list to behave like a Python list comprehension on an empty list. In other words, I wanted it to return an empty list, rather than to throw an error. For multiple lists, I wanted map to stop once the shortest list was depleted, like with Python's [f(x, y) for x, y in zip(x_list, y_list)]. As Eli points out, the srfi-1 version of map does both of these things, while the built-in (r5rs) version of map doesn't.

Comment: R5RS (http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_558) doesn't say that the lists can't be empty (as Eli Barzilay points out in the beginning of his answer)

Comment: Whoops; true. I can't even remember where I got that idea from.

Comment: I've edited the question to remove the false assertion that r5rs' map disallows empty lists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, note that `map` *does* allow empty lists, but of course if there's one empty list then all of them should be empty.

Second, have a look at the [srfi-1 version of `map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi-std/srfi-1.html#map) -- it is specifically different from the R5RS version as follows:

> This procedure is extended from its R5RS specification to allow the arguments to be of unequal length; it terminates when the shortest list runs out.

Third, most Scheme programmers would very much prefer

```
(map (lambda (arg) (+ num arg)) lst)
```

My guess is that Scheme is different from Python in a way that makes `lambda` expressions become more and more readable as you get used to the language.

And finally, there are some implementations that come with some form of a list comprehension.  For example, in [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) you can write:

```
(for/list ([arg lst]) (+ num arg))
```